# How to use Either in a case class scala

Tags: scala, either, scala-bitcoin-s

I am trying to use `Either` in a case class, but I'm getting the error that the compiler expects `ContractDescriptorTLV` but found  `Either[ContractDescriptorTLV, ujson.Value]`. I think the problem is that I'm not using `Either` correctly but I'm not sure.

```
case class CreateContractInfo(
                               announcementTLV: OracleAnnouncementTLV,
                               totalCollateral: Satoshis,
                               contractDescriptorTLV: Either[ContractDescriptorTLV, ujson.Value]) {

  def contractDescriptor: ContractDescriptor = {
    ContractDescriptor.fromTLV(contractDescriptorTLV)
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, `fromTLV` sounds as if it expects an `ContractDescriptorTLV`, but you're giving it a  `contractDescriptorTLV: Either[ContractDescriptorTLV, ujson.Value]`. Since these two types are obviously completely different, the compiler warns you, which should be hardly surprising. So, what's the question?

Comment: What library do those classes come from?

Comment: What @AndreyTyukin says is completely correct. I suggest you learn more about the language first. But to give you some idea about how to handle it, the `Either[L, R]` as the name indicates, can be either an instance of `L` type parameter, or `R` type parameter. Now what if you had `ujson.Value` as the `contractDescriptorTLV`? Maybe take a look [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-either-left-right-example-option-some-none-null/) to see how to deal with them?

Comment: My suggestion would be to also return `Either[ContractDescriptor, ujson.Value]` as the return type to your `contractDescriptor` method. Or make it optional or something.

Comment: @Andrey Tyukin it's from the bitcoin library

Comment: I assume that you meant [bitcoin-s](https://bitcoin-s.org/api/org/bitcoins/core/protocol/dlc/models/ContractDescriptor%24.html).